# Solve for vector $r$ in an equation involving sum of the square elements of $r$ and the sum of the square elements of $Mr$ where $M$ is a known matrix

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, sums-of-squares, transpose

Hello stackexchange community.
I have a system of equations where the aim is finding two vectors $r$ and $c$ of lengths $t$ and $m$ respectively. There is a known matrix $M$ of shape $m\times t$ and these are the two equations:

1. $c=\frac{1}{||r||^2}Mr$
2. $r=\frac{1}{||c||^2}M^Tc$

where $M^T$ is the transpose of the matrix $M$, and $||v||^2$ is the square of the Euclidean norm of the vector $v$ (or the sum of the square of each entry of $v$).

Now I have boiled down the system to the following $2$ equations, but I can't go beyond what I've reached:

1. $r=\frac{||r||^2}{||Mr||^2}M^TMr$
2. $c=\frac{||c||^2}{||M^Tc||^2}MM^Tc$

Some info that might be necessary:

1. $m$ i.e. length of $r$, and $t$ i.e. length of $c$ may or may not be equal.
2. Subsequently the matrix $M$ may or may not have an inverse.

I have not been able to find any mathematical solutions on how to approach this problem.
I thought of going ahead with using sympy (which is a computer programming tool meant for solving equations using the coding language python) but I wanted to get a mathematical solution before resorting to computing.
Thanks a ton and any feedback is appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why invent the notation $M@R$, when $MR$ is already perfectly acceptable for matrix multiplication?

Comment: Ok I'll make the change. It's just that I'm a python developer and this is how we represent matrix multiplication. 
Sorry and thanks.

Comment: Using the SVD of $M$, you can reduce this to the same problem with diagonal $M$.

Comment: No problem. It seems I misread your problem at first, thinking that $R,C$ were matrices. It doesn't strictly matter, but in math, it's customary to write matrices in uppercase, and vectors and scalars in lowercase. It's also worth noting that $\text{sum}(v^2)$ is just the square of the Euclidean norm of $v$ (written $||v||^2$). You definitely don't have to change anything (it's understandable), but sticking to notation mathematicians are used to might help you get a faster answer, and might help you avoid more downvotes. If you want, I could do some minor edits to improve things?

Comment: Hey Tryst with Freedom, no I'm not Malayali.

Comment: Thanks a ton @C-RAM for letting me get familiar with the convention a little more. I'd be very grateful if you'd make the changes you feel necessary in the question. Thanks again

Comment: I have made the edit. If You're ok with it, you can accept it. Otherwise if I have made some mistake, or have changed too much in your view, you can reject it. If you realize later that you prefer your original, you can always revert it to the past one. Hopefully this helps. : )

Comment: Hey @C-RAM , thanks for the edits you have implemented. I'm going forward with the changes you've made. Your efforts and help are much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Jean-Claude Arbaut , so I went and did a quick revision and research on SVD and diagonalization and I couldn't really understand what you meant. It'd be a great help if you could let me know your idea a little more please. Thanks

Comment: The SVD decomposition of $M$ is $M=USV^T$ with orthogonal $U$ and $V$, and diagonal $S$. Plugging this in your equations, you can write $c=\frac{1}{\|r\|^2}USV^Tr$ and $r=\frac{1}{\|c\|^2}VSU^Tc$. With $r'=V^Tr$ and $c'=U^Tc$, and noting $\|r'\|=\|r\|=$ and $\|c'\|=\|c\|=$ because $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal, this simplifies to $r'=\frac{1}{\|c'\|^2}Sc'$ and $c'=\frac{1}{\|r'\|^2}Sr'$. This should be easier to solve, as the product of a diagonal matrix and a vector is much simpler.

Comment: Hey @Jean-Claude Arbaut , this is a beautiful simplification, thanks a ton! Will work on this going forward. For anyone who might be confused about this comment check out this link: https://tinyurl.com/yfanabvr . It shows (besides other things) how & why multiplying with the orthogonal matrix preserves the norm . In short words though you can perceive any matrix as a tool to perform a geometric transformation and an orthogonal matrix represents a special transformation which only reflects a vector in a plane &/or rotates it but NEVER changes it's length. That's why Euclidian norm is unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$ c = \dfrac{1}{\| r \|^2 } M r $

and

$ r = \dfrac{1}{\| c \|^2 } M^T c $

Premultiply the first equation by $M^T$ and the second equation by $M$ and use the other equation, respectively, you get

$ \| c \|^2 r = \dfrac{1}{\| r \| ^2 } M^T M r $

and

$ \| r \|^2 c = \dfrac{1}{\| c \|^2 } M M^T c $

Hence,

$ (  \| r \|^2 \| c \|^2 I - M^T M ) r = 0 $

and

$ (  \| r \|^2 \| c \|^2 I - M M^T) c = 0 $

The last two equations imply that non-zero $r$ is an eigenvector of $M^T M$ associated with the eigenvalue ($\lambda = \| r \|^2 \| c \|^2$).  Similarly, $c$ is an eigenvector of $M M^T$ associated with the same eigenvalue.

Now $M^TM$ and $M M^T$ share the same eigenvalues and for the bigger matrix, the additional eigenvalues are zeroes.  So to solve for $r$ and $c$, take a non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M^T M $ (which is also an eigenvalue of $M M^T$ ), and select $\| r \|$ and $\| c \|$ anyway you wish such that they're both positive and the product of their squares is equal to $\lambda$.

Next find the unit eigenvector associated with $\lambda$ for the matrix $M^T M$, and scale it by $\| r \| $ that you choose earlier, and this will give you the vector $r$.

Similarly, find the unit eigenvector associated with $\lambda$ for the matrix $M M^T$ and scale it $\| c \|$, and this will give you the vector $c$.

You can do this over all the non-zero eigenvalues of $M^T M$ (or $M M^T$ ).

**EDIT:**

The method outlined above gives the correct $r$ and $c$ up to a sign, so after finding $r$ and $c$, check the equality of the first equation.  If the left hand side is the negative of the right hand side, then just flip one of the two vectors ($r$ or $c$).  With this, both equations will be satisfied.  Or better still, after finding $r$, just use the first equation to calculate $c$ directly.

Comment: Hey @Nathalie , this makes perfect sense and it's beautiful. Thanks a ton! Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I could help.